# Properties of a sum over the root-of-unity expression of polynomials over a finite field

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

Consider a bivariate polynomial over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_n$ of the form:
$$f(x,y) = c\cdot xy + g(y)$$

where $c$ is some non-zero constant and $g$ is some univariate polynomial.

Let $\omega_n$ be a primitive  $n$th root-of-unity. Consider the function $h : \mathbb{Z_n} \to \mathbb{C}$:
$$h(x) = \sum_{y\in \mathbb{Z}_n} \omega_n^{f(x,y)}$$

I'm interested in when $h$ corresponds to a function over the same finite field, i.e. when the codomain of $h$ (up to a scalar) consists of $n$th roots-of-unity.

For example, take $f$ to be the polynomial $xy+y^2$ over $\mathbb{Z_5}$. This gives the following evaluations of $h(x)$:

$$h(0) = \omega_n^{0} + \omega_n^{1} + \omega_n^{4} + \omega_n^{4} + \omega_n^{1}$$
$$h(1) = \omega_n^{0} + \omega_n^{2} + \omega_n^{1} + \omega_n^{2} + \omega_n^{0}$$
$$h(2) = \omega_n^{0} + \omega_n^{3} + \omega_n^{3} + \omega_n^{0} + \omega_n^{4}$$
$$h(3) = \omega_n^{0} + \omega_n^{4} + \omega_n^{0} + \omega_n^{3} + \omega_n^{3}$$
$$h(4) = \omega_n^{0} + \omega_n^{0} + \omega_n^{2} + \omega_n^{1} + \omega_n^{2}$$

Note that $h(1) = h(4) = \omega_n^{1}\cdot h(0)$ and $h(2) = h(3) = \omega_n^{4}\cdot h(0)$. Therefore, taking the value of $h(0)$ as a scalar, $h(x)$ is equivalent to the function $x^2$ over $\mathbb{Z_5}$ (i.e. 0,1,4,4,1).

It seems that when $g$ is quadratic, $h$ corresponds to a quadratic function (over the finite field) as well (although not always identical as in the case above). Is this true? If so, what exactly is the relationship between $f$ and the function corresponding to $h$?

Similarly, it seems that when $g$ is cubic or above, $h$ does not correspond to a function over the finite field. Is this always true?

I'm sure there must be better terms to explain what I'm describing here - any pointers to relevant fields would also be helpful!

Comment: I'm struggling to find a good reference for this specific problem, but polynomial functions on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ have been extensively studied, including characterizations of functions on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ that can be expressed as various types of polynomials. Many elementary number theory books (*e.g.*, Borevich-Shafarevich) establish foundational results about solutions to polynomial congruences modulo $n$ and the values character sums using elementary methods. I'll post a reference if I remember one but just thought I'd help start the discussion here. `:)`

Comment: Thanks Dan! Are you aware of any particularly special properties of quadratic polynomials on finite fields (compared to those of higher degree)? I did find [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135949/a-question-on-maps-from-mathbbz-p-mathbbz-to-itself) which doesn't seem directly useful but certainly provided avenues to explore.

Comment: This is a kind of a discrete Fourier Transform of $g$ (or of $\omega^{g(y)}$ if you want to write it that way). The special restriction is that you want the components of the transform to have equal magnitudes and phases differing by a multiple of $2\pi/n$. Imma bit drunk now, but I think it will work for quadratics. May be Gauss' sums come to the fore (and there may be exceptions)? I'll come back to this after I catch some shut-eye (1am now).

Comment: Jyrki: That makes some sense so far; I look forward to your sober thoughts! For what it's worth, I do expect quadratics to "work" (i.e. map to quadratic functions). I'd mostly like to know how to prove that, and if it always fails for cubic and above (and if not, when does it work/fail?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works out as follows whenever $g$ is a quadratic polynomial and $n>2$, i.e. $n=p$ is an odd prime.

Let's write
$$
g(x)=a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0
$$
for some coefficients $a_0,a_1,a_2\in\Bbb{Z}_p,a_2\neq0$. All we need to do is to complete the square in the exponent. That is, let's rewrite
$$
cxy+g(y)=a_2y^2+(a_1+cx)y+a_0=a_2\left(y+\frac{a_1+cx}{2a_2}\right)^2+a_0-\frac{(a_1+cx)^2}{4a_2}.
$$
In the definition of $h$ the variable $x$ is a constant in the summation. Therefore we can as well use $t=y+(a_1+cx)/(2a_2)$ as the variable in the summation: when $y$ ranges over the field $\Bbb{Z}_p$ so does $t$. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
h(x)&=\sum_{t\in\Bbb{F}_p}\omega^{a_2t^2+a_0-((a_1+cx)/(2a_2))^2}\\
&=\omega^{a_0-(a_1+cx)^2/(4a_2)}\sum_{t\in\Bbb{Z}_p}\omega^{a_2t^2}\\
&=\omega^{p(x)} S(a_2),
\end{aligned}
$$
where 
$$
p(x)=-\frac{c^2}{4a_2}x^2-\frac{ca_1}{2a_2}x-\frac{a_1^2-4a_0a_2}{4a_2}\in\Bbb{Z}_p[x]
$$
is the quadratic function corresponding to $h$, and the constant (independent of $x$!)
$$
S(a_2)=\sum_{t\in\Bbb{Z}_p}\omega^{a_2t^2}
$$
is, indeed, a Gauss' sum.

The Gauss' sum is a complex number with absolute value equal to $\sqrt p$. When $a_2=1$, and $\omega=e^{2\pi i/p}$ it is known that $S(1)=\sqrt{p}$, if $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, and $S(1)=i\sqrt{p}$, if $p\equiv-1\pmod4.$ See for example [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum) for some basic properties of Gauss' sums. A textbook would be better. Number theorists probably recommend Ireland & Rosen, books on Finite Fields such as Lidl & Niederreiter will also have this (and generalizations to other finite fields).

Comment: What probably happens when $g$ is cubic or higher is that the absolute values of $h(x)$ will (usually) depend on $x$. In the quadratic case they all have absolute value $\sqrt p$, and we can start looking at the variation of their phases.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki, that fits very nicely. I'll read up properly on Gauss sums. When you say "will (usually) depend on x", do you have any examples of it not doing so? (If it doesn't depend on x, will it necessarily be a Gauss sum?)

Comment: I think that there are some other special cases where this happens. I would use *bent function* as a keyword in a search engine. They applications in crypto and such. The first promising looking hit is [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316585900494).